# Problem with using a Hashmap with a custom inner class

Tags: java, hashmap

I have code that looks like the following:

```
private void MethodToDo(SpecialObject o) {
    Map<InfoObj, Integer> totalNeeds = new HashMap<InfoObj, Integer>();

    for (ListObject obj : o.getListOfObjects()) {
        InfoObj infoObj = new InfoObj(obj.getTitle(), obj.getId());
        Integer need = totalNeeds.get(infoObj);

        if (need == null) {
           need = new Integer(obj.getNeeded());
        } else {
           need = need + obj.getNeeded();
        }
        totalNeeds.put(infoObj, need); 
    }
}
```

The object is a private inner class (in the same class as that method) that looks like this:

```
private class InfoObj {
    private String  title;
    private Integer id;

    public InfoObj(String title, Integer id) {
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object io2) {
        if (this == io2) { return true; }
        if ( !(io2 instanceof InfoObj) ) { return false; }
        InfoObj temp = (InfoObj) io2;
        return this.id.equals(temp.id) && this.title.equals(temp.title);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 7;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((this.title == null) ? 0 : this.title.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((this.id == null) ? 0 : this.id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

However, despite overriding the equals and hashCode methods, the hashMap will still contain repeat keys (as in title and id are equivalent...but still show up in multiple places). I think I'm doing everything correctly, but realize I could be missing something...

Also, I know there are repeat keys because I loop through the keySet and output the results, which results in objects with the same title and id showing up multiple times.

Comment: Does *repeat results* means duplicate keys or duplicate values?

Comment: Do you have a SSCCE that displays the duplicate keys?  Are you sure there are duplicates?

Comment: Don't believe this has anything to do with InfoObj being inner.  Does your hashCode() get called?

Comment: It means repeat keys. And I got a display of the duplicate keys.

Comment: So `java.util.HashMap.keySet()` returns a given key several times?
Given that a key is identified by an instance of `InfoObj`'s `id` and `title` attributes.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that seems to be a problem. Need more debugging on your side to make sure that the title and integer are indeed unique for InfoObj.

Comment: Yup, tried running his code with a `SpecialObject` implementation that would simply return a list of 20 `ListObjects` for `getListOfObjects()`, and an implementation of `ListObject` that on construction would get one of three random titles and one of three random ids. Ran it a couple of times, it all checks out. No duplicate keys, and the totals add up. Something else must be going on. Upper/lower case issue, white space... ?

Comment: Also note `equals()` will NPE if `this.id==null` or `this.title==null`

Comment: Post the sample output showing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, a HashMap cannot contain the same keys per the implementation the same key would be:

```
(e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
```

And since you are following the contract for equals and hashcode, any object you create here:

```
InfoObj infoObj = new InfoObj(obj.getTitle(), obj.getId());
```

With the same id and title, will be considered the same `key`, and if the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Comment: I do believe I misspoke. The keys are repeating, which is causing confusion. As if the objects being used for the keys are not the same.

Comment: @Unknown If the keys are repeating then the previous value will get replaced with the new key value, key equality is indeed determined by your override of the equals method. So any object you create with the same id and title will replace the previous value on the HashMap.

Comment: @OscarMk That's exactly what he wants, but apparently duplicate keys do appear. The `equals` and `hashCode` methods look alright, so it's quite odd. Unknown, can you give an example? Maybe paste some output from an entry listing of the HashMap with dupe keys.

Comment: @G_H Then there is nothing wrong with the code, has to be something else not in that code.

Comment: I did a double check for output...and the output was in the wrong place. Further code checking made it apparent that the code was fine, but the output was confusing and incorrect. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is OK here.